# How to sign up users to azure ad using xamarinforms and graph API

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-graph-api

Hi guys I am a bit new to azure, so im trying to implement a sign up functionality on my mobile xamarinforms app, I'm  not quite sure if I need to use graph API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users to register my users through the app using this API, the challenge i am facing is that if I use the API it needs a token which I don't know which token needs to be passed since a new user is registering to my app to gain access. Is there a docs that can help or I need to use a different approach to signup users to my app?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the access token:
[image]

Microsoft identity platform authentication libraries for mobile applications:

[image]

Please refer this documment:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries#mobile-application